# How to connect to a postgreSQL database hosted locally on my PC from google colab?

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect to a postgreSQL database on my PC from google colab. I'm using sqlalchemy to attempt this. I have a table named mdl_assign_grades which I'm trying to access. Here's my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxxx@localhost:5432/sess1920sem1')

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

assignment_grades = pd.read_sql_table('mdl_assign_grades', engine)
```

To which I get the following error

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in __init__(self, engine, connection, _has_events, _allow_revalidate, _allow_autobegin)
    144             try:
--> 145                 self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
    146             except dialect.loaded_dbapi.Error as err:

40 frames
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    120 
    121     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 122     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    123     if cursor_factory is not None:
    124         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

I have changed the pg_hba.conf to listen to all addresses.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

My postgresql.conf file looks like this (showing a part of it only)

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = ''   # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - TCP settings -
# see "man tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_user_timeout = 0           # TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, in milliseconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default

#client_connection_check_interval = 0   # time between checks for client
                    # disconnection while running queries;
                    # 0 for never

# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#password_encryption = scram-sha-256    # scram-sha-256 or md5
#db_user_namespace = off

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:${sysconfdir}/krb5.keytab'
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - SSL -

#ssl = off
#ssl_ca_file = ''
#ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_crl_dir = ''
#ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off
```

Comment: If this code is running on GCP, then 'localhost' means local to *it*, not local to *you*.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I started the server from the services.msc. I also created a new rule to allow connections using TCP/IP

Comment: @jjanes so I should change the server name here? If so, what should I put here?

Comment: Your server needs a public IP address. But this is a networking question, not a DBA question.